# How to Validate Duplicate Key values in JSON request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
{
  "number": 1165,
  "lineItems": [{
    "itemId": 1,
    "dynamicfields": {
      "styleId": "V-Neck",
      "style": "T-SHIRTS",
      "cost": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "itemId": 2,
    "dynamicfields": {
      "styleId": "V-Neck",
      "style": "T-SHIRTS",
      "cost": 30
    }
  }]
}
```

How can I validate dynamic fields for two different item id is same? I need to show validation message saying duplicate dynamic fields should not allow.

I have done some RND but there I am finding for JSON Keys duplication but I need Key Values duplication check.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET (Framework). Please tag appropriately.

Comment: You have to define your requirements better. What are "duplicate dynamic fields", **exactly**? Do you mean this payload should give an error because _all_ fields of itemId 1 are repeated in itemId 2? And/or their values? This will require custom validation.

Comment: This needs work, the question is ambiguous and unclear

Comment: Yes , You are right @CodeCaster,it has to give error because all fields of itemId 1 present in itemId 2 .It had check for all fields of ItemId 1 and ItemId 2.

Comment: deserialize, get all the item that don't alow duplicate. Group and count the unic field. and if one is >1, then you can display what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo to check json data.

Models:

```
public class ModelB{
        public int number { get; set; }
        public List<LineItem> lineItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class LineItem
    {
        public int itemId { get; set; }
        public Dynamicfields dynamicfields { get; set; }

    }
    public class Dynamicfields {
        public string styleId { get; set; }
        public string style { get; set; }
        public int cost { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
 public string CheckRepeat([FromBody]ModelB modelB)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < modelB.lineItems.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                if (modelB.lineItems.Where(l => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l.dynamicfields) == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelB.lineItems[i].dynamicfields)).Count() > 1)
                {
                    return "duplicate dynamic fields should not allow";
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

result:
[image]

If you get jsondata,you can convert it to ModelB with:

```
ModelB modelB=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelB>(jsondata);
```